# Update State of a Component from Another in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, syntax, jsx

I'm following this article **(original implementation Sibling Sibling)**:
[Update state cross component](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1215984/Update-State-of-a-Component-from-Another-in-React)

The example works perfectly. But when I try to separate each class to each .js file, then using import/export to call/bind each other. It (the updating state) doesn't work anymore.
The structure like this:

**Sibling1.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
<-- some declare style -->

export function updateText(text) {
  this.setState({text})
}

export class Sibling1 extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div style={{ ...style.topLabel, color: secondaryColor }}>I am Sibling 1</div>
        <input style={style.textBox} type="text"
               placeholder="Write text" onChange={(e) => updateText(e.target.value)} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**Example.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import * as sibling1 from './Sibling1'; //is this good?
import {Sibling1} from './Sibling1';    //is this good?

<-- some declare style, variable -->

class Sibling2 extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      text: "Initial State"
    }
    sibling1.updateText = sibling1.updateText.bind(this)  //is this good binding?
  }
  render() {
    console.log('Sibling2.state : ', this.state);
    return (
      <div>
        <div style={{ ...style.topLabel, color: primaryColor }}>I am Sibling 2</div>
        <div style={style.label}>{this.state.text}</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Example3 extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Sibling1 />
        <Sibling2 />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Example3;
```

I am simply expecting Sibling1 can change the state of Sibling2 (like the original implementation), but cannot.
I guess that my **bind(this)** doesn't bind the right context. 
Can somebody tell me what are differences between the original implementation (article above) and my approach (separate to multi .js files)?

Comment: What do you think `this` will be in the extracted `updateText` function in `Sibling1.js` file? That should be a function in the component, not a random, free-floating function. It's not clear to me what you're trying to do or why your state is even in `Sibling2` if you need to update it in this way--it looks like it should be in `Example3` and function props passed to `Sibling1`. Or switch state management altogether and use something Redux-like etc.

Comment: @DaveNewton: I am expecting Sibling2's states also change every time I input string into Sibling1.

Comment: Then I would do as I suggested; the state appears to belong to `Example3`, is modified by `Sibling1`, and consumed by `Sibling2`. Is there an explicit reason to keep the state in `Sibling2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React kinda forces you to use a one way data flow. So you can't just update the state of Sibling1 from within Sibling2.

As Dinesh Pandiyan mentions in his example that you normally would have a parent component that controls the state of both the siblings. Your code would then look like this:

**Sibling1.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
<-- some declare style -->

export class Sibling1 extends Component {
  function updateText(text) {
    // Use updateText function from props.
    // Props are like state but not controlled by the component itself
    // The value is passed to the component from outside
    this.props.updateText(text)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div style={{ ...style.topLabel, color: secondaryColor }}>I am Sibling 1</div>
        <input style={style.textBox} type="text"
               placeholder="Write text" 
               onChange={(e) => this.updateText(e.target.value).bind(this)} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**Example.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Sibling1 } from './Sibling1';    // This is good.
import Sibling1 from './Sibling1'; // This is also possible if you use export default class instead of export class

<-- some declare style, variable -->

class Sibling2 extends Component {
  // Use same function as in Sibling1.
  function updateText(text) {
      this.props.updateText(text)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div style={{ ...style.topLabel, color: primaryColor }}>I am Sibling 2</div>
        <div style={style.label}>{this.props.text}</div> // changed state to props
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Example3 extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);


    this.state = {
      text: "Initial state"
    };
  }

  // Control state from parent component
  function updateText(
    this.setState({ text: text });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Sibling1 updateText={this.updateText.bind(this)}/>
        <Sibling2 updateText={this.updateText.bind(this)} text={this.state.text} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Example3;
```

Answer (score 2):

`updateText()` should be bound to a component. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here but `updateText()` might not work in Sibling1 if context changes.

You could try binding `updateText()` in both components (already bound in Sibling2).

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export function updateText(text) {
  this.setState({text})
}

export class Sibling1 extends Component {
  constructor() {
    updateText = updateText.bind(this)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div style={{ ...style.topLabel, color: secondaryColor }}>I am Sibling 1</div>
        <input style={style.textBox} type="text"
               placeholder="Write text" onChange={(e) => updateText(e.target.value)} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Usually state is controlled in parent component if two child components need to share the state and only the handler is passed down to the chilren.